# Send Tkinter Text to another function with button

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

I create a tkinter window ('window3' as shown) by a button trigger. I want have a function that takes data from 'KonuIcerik' ScrolledText on 'window3' then sends it to function 'def Finish():'

I know my problem is about using functions but i couldnt fix it. I need a little help

**Error: "KonuIcerik" is not defined**

```
    def KonuOlusturButtonu():
        window3= Toplevel(root)
        window3.geometry(f'{root_width}x{root_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
        window3.title("Konu Oluştur")
        window3.resizable(False, False)
        window3.configure(background='#0a0a0a')

        # Create ScrolledText widget
        KonuIcerik = ScrolledText(window3, width=96,  height=30)
        KonuIcerik.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor=CENTER)

        # Create Button widget
        button_konubitir = Button(window3, text ="Bitir ve Yayınla", command = Finish())
        button_konubitir.config( height = 2, width = 30 )
        button_konubitir.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.92, anchor=CENTER)

    def Finish():
        KonuIcerikText = KonuIcerik.get()
        print(KonuIcerikText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the function to accept an argument:

```py
def Finish(widget):
    KonuIcerikText = widget.get('0.0', 'end')
    print(KonuIcerikText);
```

Then change the command by creating a `lambda` to call it later and by passing the `widget` argument to be used by the function to get the text:

```py
button_konubitir = Button(window3, text="Bitir ve Yayınla", command=lambda: Finish(KonuIcerik))
```

See also:

- [Why is the command bound to a Button or event executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared)
- I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations. Class methods have one blank line around them.

Comment: Thank you! Very educative answer!